# Kotlin and generic constructors leave me baffled

Tags: generics, constructor, kotlin

Not understanding Kotlin in combination with Generics.

I was trying to move some of my java towards kotlin. Couple of those classes are spring-data repositories
and a generic service that takes as generic parameter a type of repository, e.g.:

```
@Transactional
interface ForumRepository : CrudRepository<Forum, Long> {
    fun findByName(name: String): Forum?
}
```

Then the GenericKotlinService :

```
abstract class GenericKotlinService<T>(val repository: CrudRepository<Any, Serializable>) {
    fun <T> findOne(id: Serializable): T {
        return repository.findOne(id) as T
    }
    fun delete(id: Any) {
        repository.delete(id)
    }
}
```

However, now when I try to create a service that uses this generic service with a specific crudRepository
I always get errors, e.g.

```
class ForumService @Autowired constructor(repository: ForumRepository) : GenericKotlinService<Forum>(repository) {
    open fun findByName(name: String) = repository.findByName(name)
}
```

or

```
class ForumService : GenericKotlinService<Forum> {
    @Autowired
    constructor(repository: ForumRepository) : super(repository)
    open fun findByName(name: String) = repository.findByName(name)
}
```

The error is

```
required CrudRepository<Forum, Long> but got a ForumRepository.
```

When I use the following java GenericService:

```
public abstract class GenericService<T> {
    private final CrudRepository repository;
    public GenericService(CrudRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public T findOne(Serializable id) {
        return (T) repository.findOne(id);
    }
    public void delete(Serializable id) {
        repository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

and use this one in the ForumService:

```
class ForumService @Autowired constructor(val repository: ForumRepository) : GenericService<Forum>(repository) {
    open fun findByName(name: String) = repository.findByName(name)
}
```

everything works. I do not see how I can use my GenericKotlinService instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that `ForumRepository` is not `CrudRepository<Any, Serializable>`. But it can be convertible to `CrudRepository<Any, Serializable>` if both type parameters are in `out` positions. So you can either define the `CrudRepository` in the following way

```
interface CrudRepository<out T, out U>
```

or accept `CrudRepository` with `out` type parameters in `GenericKotlinService` constructor

```
abstract class GenericKotlinService<T>(
    val repository: CrudRepository<out Any, out Serializable>
)
```

Comment: basically this is like wildcard in Java

Comment: Since the CrudRepository is part of the spring data I can not change this easily. However when I use your version of the GenericKotlinService and use some repository calls, e.g. repository.findOne(id) I get an error : Kotlin: Out-protected type 'CrudRepository<out Any, out Serializable>' prohibits the use of public abstract fun findOne(po: ID!), so I probably have to study a bit more on the out keyword.